# Is there a way to move items from quote back to basket?

Tags: bricklink

I requested a quote on a set of parts. Got it, it was too expensive in terms of shipping, but it turns out I had only 18g of parts, when shipping would cover up to 100g. Is there a way to move parts back to my cart, so I could add additional 82g of bricks without clicking it all again? I understand some parts might not longer be available or change price. I don't really care, I just want to avoid looking them up again.

Comment: Perhaps you could accept the quote but ask the seller to leave the order open so you can add items to it. Will appear to you as a separate order, but the orders will get merged. The average bricklink seller will be more than happy to comply...

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve perhaps i could, but quotes are automatically closed after 48 hours so it is too late now. Good to know for the future, thanks, but useless for now.

Answer (score 4):

No. You cannot put items from quote back to cart, but there is a better option.

As per [help topic](https://www.bricklink.com/help.asp?helpID=2437) on Bricklink:

> You can add quote items to a wanted list at any time by clicking the **Add Quote Items to Wanted List** button on the quote summary page

Here how it looks in your quote (just at the bottom of your item list):

[image]

Once you click on that button you have an option to add items from your quote to an existing Wanted List or create a new one. This then allows you to have a list of items from quote that you can use to buy in other stores too, not just the one you've requested a quote from.

More details on how to use wanted lists when buying parts can be found in another [help article](https://www.bricklink.com/help.asp?helpID=2445) on Bricklink.